# Property 'onPremisesSyncEnabled' does not exist as a declared property or extension property

Tags: active-directory, azure-security, azure-ad-b2b, on-premises-instances, azure-ad-powershell-v2

We have requirement of getting on-premises synced users SAM Account Name and Security ID from powershell.

```
$onPremUsers = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true"

foreach ($user in $onPremUsers) {
    Write-Output "User: $($user.UserPrincipalName)"
    Write-Output "  SAM Account Name: $($user.onPremisesSamAccountName)"
    Write-Output "  SID: $($user.onPremisesSecurityIdentifier)"
    Write-Output ""
}
```

Failing with Get-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing GetUsers
Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Property 'onPremisesSyncEnabled' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.
RequestId: b968799c-3ce7-422d-83e4-29afe75655db
DateTimeStamp: Mon, 07 Aug 2023 07:23:29 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:16

- ... onPremUsers = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true"
- ```
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADUser], ApiException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUser

```
#Changed to ADMS
$onPremUsers = Get-AzureADMSUser -Filter "onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true"

foreach ($user in $onPremUsers) {
    Write-Output "User: $($user.UserPrincipalName)"
    Write-Output "  SAM Account Name: $($user.onPremisesSamAccountName)"
    Write-Output "  SID: $($user.onPremisesSecurityIdentifier)"
    Write-Output ""
}
```

User: username@******.onmicrosoft.com
SAM Account Name:
SID:

UPNs are correct but blank responses for SAM Account Name and Security ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have below **on-premises synced users** in my Azure AD tenant:

[image]

When I ran your script in my environment, I too got **same error**:

```
$onPremUsers = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true"

foreach ($user in $onPremUsers) {
    Write-Output "User: $($user.UserPrincipalName)"
    Write-Output "  SAM Account Name: $($user.onPremisesSamAccountName)"
    Write-Output "  SID: $($user.onPremisesSecurityIdentifier)"
    Write-Output ""
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran your second script, it gave me **same response** with correct UPNs but blank response for SAM Account Name and Security ID:

```
#Changed to ADMS
$onPremUsers = Get-AzureADMSUser -Filter "onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true"

foreach ($user in $onPremUsers) {
    Write-Output "User: $($user.UserPrincipalName)"
    Write-Output "  SAM Account Name: $($user.onPremisesSamAccountName)"
    Write-Output "  SID: $($user.onPremisesSecurityIdentifier)"
    Write-Output ""
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Instead of that, you can directly use below **Microsoft Graph PowerShell** commands to get **`SAM Account Name`** and **`Security ID`** of on-premises synced Azure AD users:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All"
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

Get-MgUser -Filter "onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true " -Property "userPrincipalName,onPremisesSamAccountName,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier" | Select-Object "userPrincipalName","onPremisesSamAccountName","onPremisesSecurityIdentifier"
```

**Response:**

[image]